# How can I let apps use their default notification sound on Moto G5

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G5 S, Android 7.1.1, and all (messaging?) apps are using a really annoying notification sound (the one that came by default in the phone). I would prefer that each app uses their default notification sound (like WhatsApp's whistle or Facebook's... thing). Is there a way I can set that for all apps?

Comment: Thing is, many apps don't come with a notification sound of their own. You could've just changed that global default ringtone instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said earlier you cannot choose a custom notification sound for each app, however you can change the notification sound for all apps.

Go into Settings > Sound > Default notification ringtone > choose whichever ringtone you like

Answer (score 1):

A slightly related workaround will be using a third-party notification manager application which provides **notification customizatio**n by allowing you to configure sounds/ voice alerts for any applications that you use.

One such tool is [NotifiCon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=notificon.gsy.com.notificon&hl=en).

> Features :
>
> 1. Configure the notification sound from a list of available options for each app's notifications on your device
> 2. Configure a special voice-based notification alert for notification alerts from any app (For example, you can configure your Whatsapp app
>      to say "Whatsapp", when you get a Whatsapp notification)

NB: *NotifiCon does not create new notifications, rather it provides sound/voice alerts to accompany other apps' notifications.*

*During first time installation, the app will show a few things before opening the main screen. These include permission requests, notification access requests, and write settings requests. Please grant these to allow the app to perform its functions and then press the back button (if applicable).*

Disclaimer: The author of this post has no affiliation with the above app